# How Do I instantly refresh a component of a recyclerview in android studio?

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, refresh

I have a button and when the button is clicked, I would like it to automatically update the text, the catch is that the text is coming from a server and I am parsing it via JSON. My question is how can I automatically update the text when the button is clicked without a complete refresh?

```
JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_ANSWER, (String) null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    listblogs = parseJSONResponseQuestion(response);
                    mAdapterQuestion.setBloglist(listblogs);
                    System.out.println(response);
                    System.out.println("it worked!!!");
                }

            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    System.out.println(error);

                }
            });
            mRequestQueue.add(request);
        }


        private ArrayList<Blogs> parseJSONResponseQuestion(JSONArray response) {
            if (!response.equals("")) {
                ArrayList<Blogs> blogsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                try {
                    StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject currentQuestions = response.getJSONObject(i);
                String text = currentQuestions.getString("text");
                String questionId = currentQuestions.getString("questionId");
                String votes = currentQuestions.getString("votes");
                String Answerid = currentQuestions.getString("id");
                String selectedId = currentQuestions.getString("selected");
                System.out.println(response.length() + "length");

                data.append(text + Answerid + "\n");

                System.out.println(data);
                Blogs blogs = new Blogs();
                blogs.setMtext(text);
                blogs.setVotes(votes);
                blogs.setId(Answerid);
                blogs.setSelected(selectedId);
                System.out.print(Answerid);
                listblogs.add(blogs);
            }
            System.out.println(data.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return listblogs;
}
```

The only thing I have tried it recalling the jsonarray in my listener

```
public void OnDown(View view) {
    CharSequence IdDownVote = ((TextView) ((RelativeLayout) view.getParent()).getChildAt(1)).getText();
    final RequestQueue mrequestQueue = VolleySingleton.getInstance().getRequestQueue();
    final String PUT_VOTE_DOWN = "someURL";

    StringRequest PostVoteUp = new StringRequest(Request.Method.PUT, PUT_VOTE_DOWN, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            System.out.println(response + "reponse");

        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("************Answer" + error + "error");
        }
    });
    mrequestQueue.add(PostVoteUp);

    System.out.println("VOTED DOWN");
}

public void ClickCardAnswer(View view) {
    System.out.println("YOU CLICKED THE CARD");
}
```

}

Comment: I dont know what you mean by that statement, I would like to refresh a component of my recyclerview and not the whole thing.

Comment: please provide some code...what have you tried for it...

Comment: I supplied some code

Comment: For editting +1 bro :)

Comment: Lol thanks, do you have any ideas?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102017/discussion-between-eli-and-ravindra-kushwaha).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little ambiguous, but I'll try to answer the two possible problems you might have:

1. You have updated the item in the adapter but it won't display the new content: use notifyItemChanged(int position) of the adapter class
2. You want to update the item in the adapter. Apart from the setBloglist() of the adapter class you need to make a method to update a certain item in the dataset (either by position in list or looking it up via id - I usually use the ID version). After update, see point 1 above.

Comment: The problem is not that it fails to update, It will update the chosen item, however, only on a complete refresh of the page. Therefore, I already have the notifyItemChanged, which updates my individual items, my question is how to instantly update a component without a complete refresh

Comment: If by "complete refresh of the page" you mean adapter reinitialization, then you need point 1 from my answer. Once drawn, the items do not update on the screen unless you request it. If you have many items and you scroll away and back on the changed item, is it updated?

Comment: No, If I scroll away it is not update only if I do a complete refresh or adapter reintilization.

Comment: then you didn't update the item inside the adapter, you only updated it outside (in the Activity probably). You need to update the dataset of the adapter (the one it gets the values from when displaying with onBindViewHolder()